# Defining `implicit def` w/ Implicit?

Tags: scala, implicit

Given:

```
trait Foo[A]
class B
```

and then the following `implicit def`:

```
implicit def f[A](b: B)(implicit ev: Foo[A]): String = "foo"
```

I attempted to resolve `B => String` implicitly, but it failed to compile:

```
scala> implicitly[B => String]
<console>:15: error: No implicit view available from B => String.
       implicitly[B => String]
                 ^
```

I'm guessing that the `implicit Foo[A]` is throwing a wrench, so to speak, in my implicit resolution of `B => String`.

How can I adjust the `implicitly`'s argument, i..e `B => String`, so that the above compiles?

Comment: Have you tried before `implicitly[Foo[B]]` (which is prerequisite for your implicit conversion)?

Comment: That's a good point - my mistake.

Comment: BTW an `implicit A => B` is an `implicit conversion` rather than a typeclass, which lead to the corresponding warning (as it can quickly clutter the code). Would rather use a `trait MyFunT[A] extends (A => String)`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you think of any real typrclasses that use this approach?

Comment: Added as answer to be able to use code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar code using typeclass rather than implicit conversion:

```
trait MyFunT[A] extends (A => String)

object MyFunT {
  /**Factory to easily define an instance from a fun */
  def apply[A](f: A => String): MyFunT[A] = new MyFunT[A] {
    def apply(a: A): String = f(a)
  }
}

implicit def foo[A](implicit ev: Foo[A]) = MyFunT[A] { a: A => /* do something with `a` and `ev` */ "foo" }
```

> Even if `implicit`s based/requiring other `implicit` are usual, I would advice to take care not to have "too long chain" about that.

Comment: Do you think adding the following function to `object Foo` would be a good choice too: `def instance[A](f: A => Foo[A]): Foo[A]`? I asked this question after re-reading the [Shapeless Guide](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide), where it mentions the `CsvEncoder` typeclass: https://github.com/kevinmeredith/shapeless_book_exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/net/CsvEncoder.scala#L12-L15.

Comment: Such factory function is aften called `apply` as in the sample

Comment: After reading your helpful answer and comments, it's not clear to me why it's useful to make `MyFunT` extend `(A => String)`. What, if anything, would be lost if you removed that inheritance?

Comment: It offer the possibility of using the instances of the typeclass where compatible/plain functions are expected, and it add some semantic also